# Not able to use gs_new() command to export dataframe to googlesheets

Tags: r, google-sheets

I have to create a prediction tool using javascript using the coefficients of a model I created in R. As there are a lot of coeffs, I made it a dataframe and tried to export it to sheets and use it. However, I am getting this error message. Can anyone please help to debug this problem.

```
l_model2 <- multinom(form, data = m_tab2)
coef <- as.data.frame(coef(l_model2))

gs_new(title = "model_coefs", ws_title = "coef", data = coef)

##Error
Error in (function (ss, ws = 1, input = "", anchor = "A1", byrow = FALSE,  : 
  unused argument (data = list(`(Intercept)` = c(-21.213788479214,....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gs_new()` only creates new spreadsheet, you can add data later with `gs_edit_cells()`

```
new_ws <- gs_new(title = "model_coefs", ws_title = "coef")
new_ws <- gs_edit_cells(new_ws, ws = 'coef', input = coef, trim = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
```